# How to add WCF custom binding element extensions client-side in code, without any config files?

Tags: wcf, configuration, wcf-binding, servicebus

**Situation**

I have a client library that uses the Windows Azure AppFabric Service Bus **NetTcpRelayBinding** to connect to the endpoint. The client library is hosted by an application, that is not necessarily a .NET-application. Anyway, app.config is out of the question, which means everything should be configured in code.

Machine.config is one option, but it's better if it can be avoided. A local custom proxy or a front-end server could be another option, but I'd like to explore this option first, before changing architecture that radically.

There are no problems with system bindings, but I haven't figured out or found a solution how to add the following configuration to a **ChannelFactory** in code:

```
<extensions>
  <bindingElementExtensions>
   <add name="tcpRelayTransport" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.TcpRelayTransportElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </bindingElementExtensions>

  <bindingExtensions>
   <add name="netTcpRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.NetTcpRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </bindingExtensions>
 </extensions>
```

Comment: Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.nettcprelaybinding.aspx which explains nettcprelaybinding with c# code

Comment: @Rajesh That example still assumes that the Service Bus binding extensions (like that NetTcpRelayBinding) are in the app.config or machine.config.

Comment: In that case does your question mean on how to add the bindingElementExtensions via C# code?

Comment: @Rajesh Yes, I think that would have been more accurate title - corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution that has now been tested. Hopefully it makes clear, what the problem really was and maybe it helps somebody else with a similar problem. Credits to co-worker, who had the time to investigate the issue.

The solution was to edit dynamically the configuration and add the reference to the required **Binding Element Extensions** (*without* app.config in any layer or without changing machine.config in client machines):

```
        var service = ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None));

        var tcpRelayTransportExtension = new ExtensionElement("tcpRelayTransport", "Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.TcpRelayTransportElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35");
        var netTcpRelayTransportExtension = new ExtensionElement("netTcpRelayBinding", "Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.NetTcpRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35");

        if (service.Extensions.BindingElementExtensions.ContainsKey(tcpRelayTransportExtension.Name) == false)
        {
            service.Extensions.BindingElementExtensions.Add(tcpRelayTransportExtension);
        }

        if (service.Extensions.BindingElementExtensions.ContainsKey(netTcpRelayTransportExtension.Name) == false)
        {
            service.Extensions.BindingElementExtensions.Add(netTcpRelayTransportExtension);
        }
```

Thanks to everyone who tried to help, though!

Answer (score 1):

You can add the binding element extension via code by writing a custom service host factory. A similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582270/add-a-binding-extension-via-code)

Based on your type of WCF service you just need to inherit the appropriate servicehostfactory class when writing a custom service host factory. For example as shown below:

1. [How to build a custom service host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395224.aspx)
2. If building a REST WCF Service use [WebServiceHostFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.webservicehostfactory.aspx)
3. If building a WCF service use [ServiceHostFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.servicehostfactory.aspx)

Comment: Those are good examples, but they are for the ServiceHost, server-side, which isn't a problem. My problem is in the client-side (ChannelFactory)

Answer (score 0):

A sample for this without config is available here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Relayed-Messaging-Windows-0d2cede3

Following is the code snippet:

```
ChannelFactory<IEchoChannel> channelFactory = null; 
IEchoChannel channel = null; 
try 
{
    //Create a Behavior for the Credentials 
    TransportClientEndpointBehavior sharedSecretServiceBusCredential = new TransportClientEndpointBehavior(); 
    sharedSecretServiceBusCredential.TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedSecretTokenProvider(issuerName, issuerSecret); 

    //Create a Channel Factory 
    channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IEchoChannel>(new NetTcpRelayBinding(), new EndpointAddress(serviceAddress)); 
    channelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(sharedSecretServiceBusCredential); 

    LogMessage("Opening channel to: {0}", serviceAddress); 
    channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel(); 
    channel.Open(); 

    LogMessage("Sending: {0}", echoTextBox.Text); 
    string echoedText = channel.Echo(echoTextBox.Text); 
    LogMessage("Received: {0}", echoedText); 
    echoTextBox.Text = string.Empty; 

    LogMessage("Closing channel"); 
    channel.Close(); 
    LogMessage("Closing factory"); 
    channelFactory.Close(); 
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
        LogMessage("Error sending: {0}<br/>{1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace.Replace("\n", "<br/>")); 

        // Close the channel and factory properly 
        if (channel != null) 
        { 
            CloseCommunicationObject(channel); 
        } 
        if (channelFactory != null) 
        { 
            CloseCommunicationObject(channelFactory); 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but that sample still has that bindingExtensions -element in the WebRole's web.config, which is the problem.